# Error when I'm trying to do a POST request in Fiware

Tags: post, request, fiware

I'm developing a script to do a POST request to Orion Context Broker of Fiware. The problem is that a receive an error:

> "ContextLengthRequired"

, but I have `Context-Length` header in the request.

This is the error when I tried node fiware.js

```
{
  "error":"ContentLengthRequired",
  "description":"Zero/No Content-Length in PUT/POST/PATCH request"
}
```

This is the code in the file **fiware.js**:

```js
var request = require('request');

var entity = {
  "id": "Room6",
  "type": "Room",
  "temperature": {
    "value": 23,
    "type": "Float"
  },
  "pressure": {
    "value": 700,
    "type": "Float"
  }
};

var jsonObject = JSON.stringify(entity);
var aux = jsonObject.toString();
aux = aux.length;

var peticion = {
  url: "http://127.0.0.1:1026/v2/entities",
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Length": aux,
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  data: jsonObject
};

request(peticion, function(error, response, body) {
  console.log(error);
  console.log(body);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the variable peticion from this:

> var peticion = {
>     url: "http://127.0.0.1:1026/v2/entities",
>     method: "POST",
>     headers: {
>       "Content-Length": aux,
>       "Content-Type": "application/json"
>     },
>     **data**: jsonObject
>   };

To this one:

> var peticion = {
>     url: "http://127.0.0.1:1026/v2/entities",
>     method: "POST",
>     headers: {
>       "Content-Length": aux,
>       "Content-Type": "application/json"
>     },
>     **body**: jsonObject
>   };